# Verification of enterprise bean failed [Section: 16.2]

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, ejb, ejb-2.x

I am working on one of the legacy system written in EJB 2.0. I updated few classes in one the EJB module using Eclipse. Since I am using Eclipse and upon changing file it auto build the code. I copied the `.class` files of the changed java classes, downloaded the working / deployed jar of that EJB module from server and copy/replaced the changed `.class` files in the Jar. But, when I try to deploy that jar in the JBoss. It is giving me below error. I am stuck on it since morning, have tried lots of things but still no success.

[image: Error I am getting]

Can somebody give me a hint what is the reason of this error ? I am sure it is something related to compiling and in generating binary files. Because when I built it on my colleague laptop, and deployed it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, that was a real real legacy system. I tried Java Versions until 1.6, thought it should work with it. I just compiled it using Java 1.5 and the error has gone and ejb is deployed now. Had to do changes in Eclipse.

[image]